How do DAW's process sends/returns with busses if they are routed to themselves?
I'm looking into creating the sends/returns/busses logic for my own audio application. When checking existing DAW's (Logic Pro / Ableton Live) I noticed you can make a routing-loop by sending busses/aux to itself (depending on the DAW).
In the image below you can see a simple example. In the 'A Delay' bus is 'sent' to itself.

I was wondering if anyone has an idea how this is processed. As I would expect there to be some infinite loop or at least a very high CPU load. Or is there some other trick I might be missing?

I’ve never written a DAW, but I’m pretty sure the answer is that the feedback signal is slightly delayed (by the length of the audio buffer)

As an aside, it’s a good idea to use a Limiter when experimenting with feedback loops to make sure it doesn’t go out of control to a damaging level!

I just tested it with Logic Pro and I think you're right. It only sends a delayed signal when there is a loop somewhere in the route. By default it will just process the signal without any delay. When a loop is introduced the whole signal seems to be delayed, even if that loop is not audible (for example when the 'send' which causes the loop is turned off). Thanks for the help!
